# Checkboxes checked into JSON Format in SpringMVC

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am working on a spring MVC application. I have a sitaution where i need to check some checkboxes from UI and save the checked values in the form of JSON in the backend and i need to convert that into a string.

The picture shows more.

So i want to save like:

```
[{
  Coast : 'East',
  States : [ 'NY', 'MI' ]
},{
Coast : 'Central',
States : [ 'TX', 'OK' ] 
}].
```

Please suggest me how can i implement this. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague so I'm going to assume because you've used the `json` tag that you're asking for help on how to model this information in JSON and handle it within your Spring app.

You probably want to restructure your JSON schema to support extra fields being set per state. Instead of `States` being a list of strings, you could change it to a list of objects which has a `name` and `selected` field.

I'd also recommend you change the keys in your JSON to be lower case, this enables more fluent mapping between your JSON and model classes.

For example, MI is selected in the below JSON, whereas NY isn't:

```
[{
  "coast": "East",
  "states": [{
    "name": "NY",
    "selected": true
  }, {
    "name": "MI",
    "selected": false
  }]
}, {
  ...same again for West and Central
}]
```

You could then have some classes along the lines of and use Jackson to map between them:

```
public class Region {
    String coast;
    List<State> states;
}

public class State {
    String name;
    boolean selected;
}
```

Comment: Hi dan.jones .Thanks for the reply.I did not used any JSON tag here.  But my question is how do we convert into json format based on the checkbox selection from the UI and save it in the backend java.

Comment: The `json` tag is on the question, so if you didn't add it SO must have done automatically.. In any case, you're not being very specific. Are you using a database already, and in which case what db are you using? If not, do a bit more research into [spring-data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) and consider your options. Once you've got a db set up and you've designed your schema in a way similar to my answer, you can simply make a HTTP POST and have your backend persist it